# Users spoofing domain name

Tags: c#, active-directory

We currently have a winforms app that allows users to log in in order to access the system.  The authentication system is a custom made kludge.  I'm working on a implementing a change that links users NT username and domainname to their existing custom account so that they don't need to repeatedly log in.  I'm using WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name then storing that information in a database table that maps to their old accountid.  What I'm wondering is if it would be possible for a user to vpn into the network with a computer name that mirrors the real domain name?  This could potentially give a rogue user access to someone elses account. I guess the real question is: is there a way to differentiate between the sql servers domain and a users domain without just doing a string compare on the names.

Comment: I may not understand your situation completely. It sounds like you are using SQL authentication to access the database and store the connection string somewhere in your winapp. If that's the case, people may steal your connection string from the winapp and gain access to your database. About your concern, you can consider to store SID instead of username and domain name. Yes, this is still not secured but at least this sets the bar higher. There is no available tool on the web that helps you to make a fake SID in the domain. I think we may still be able to do that but it should be very tricky

Comment: Thanks Harvey, this is the path I took.  I'm now storing the token owners ssid with the username/domain name information.  This should effectively solve the problem of someone setting up there own domain and using VPN to impersonate another user.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it would if your app was using SQL Authentication to access the database.  If you change the Database connection to use trusted authentication then the SQL Server will authenticate the login against the domain controller.  So despite the user having access to the application they wouldn't be able to access the database driving the applicaiton.  If you did this you could also move the capturing of the user name to a SQL Server stored procedure which would ensure that the name captured matched that of the Domain rather than the local users.

Comment: I agree this is the optimum way to go but this change would be huge and will not be approved by mgmt.

Comment: +1 I vote for this.  Let the management decide whether they want security or they want to save money on development

Answer (score 1):

THE SERVER MUST NOT TRUST THE CLIENT.

If the client can get and use credentials to log in to the database server you're toast.

If your server is only a database server and your application does not use trusted connections and your application does not prompt for db credentials you're toast. (See previous statement.)

I'm lazy. I'll patch WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name to return "Administrator" if I feel like it.

Comment: We've been toast for a decade now :)  In reality the risk is low.  The db server is on a corporate network but authorized users do have vpn access.  I think if I could just ensure the client were on the same domain as the db server that would good enough.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  That's what I'm worried about.  However a simple check that ensures that the client is in the same domain as the db server would alleviate the problem.  If the client is not in the correct domain then access denied.  We are already aware that our apps are not air-tight secure.  We live with the risk because 1.  It's on a private corporate network and 2.  The information stored in the system is not very exciting.  Someone would gain very little by hacking into our system.